# Button on click go from activity in another activity React-native

Tags: ubuntu, react-native

I create the button with:

```
<Button
    containerStyle={{padding:10, height:45, overflow:'hidden', borderRadius:7,marginTop: 60, backgroundColor: 'white'}}
    style={styles.button}
    onClick={this.handlePress}>
    We Are
</Button>
```

And the handlePress:

```
handlePress (event) {
   require('./we-are.js')
   // alert("ciaooo")
}
```

However when I click on the button nothing happens. I try it with an alert this works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind that function so you will make the `this` to refer to the context you are expecting when invoking the actual function. There are several ways to achieve this, you can try:

```
onClick={ this.handlePress.bind(this) }
```

Or use arrow functions (auto-binding):

```
onClick={() => { this.handlePress() } }
```

Or in the constructor of your component (assuming you use `class` syntax):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
}
```

This is more efficient since you are not creating a new function every time you re-render.

In React Native, you can actually do it in a nicer way (since it includes the babel plugin for this already):

```
handlePress = (event) => {
  ...
}
```